# 4x4 with a steel pipe running through

Tags: wood

Given two 4x4's with a 1/2" steel pipe running through the middle, how much weight can the posts support? Is there a chance the wood will split?

[image]

Comment: What's the intent? A jungle gym or pull-up bar? Something like that?

Comment: How tall are the posts? Are they on a concrete foundation or just a hole in the ground?

Comment: The posts will probably support more than the pipe will, assuming they're secured as to be immovable. But yes, there's a chance. Quality and condition matter, as does specific loading.

Comment: And rather than asking such a specific engineering question, you should ask whether the intended purpose will be achieved. Edit to describe your project.

Comment: Chin up bar? The only issue that you'll have it keeping the posts upright. Make sure that they are buried in the ground well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axial compressive strength of a worst-case 4x4 post exceeds 3,000 lbs., could be as high as 13,000 lbs, depending on the height and type of wood. Yes, the wood can possibly split, but that's always a risk with wood. As mentioned, the pipe is likely the weakest link here, but we still don't know your purpose so this is all still theoretical.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing you intend it for a pull-up bar. That 1/2 will easily hold 400 lbs, possibly not at one point but at one time, I weighed almost that much and ma and my son were doing pull-ups, he said I made the posts wobble but the bar is still there 20 years later.